# BloomFilter Python

Tags: python, bloom-filter

I am new to python and trying to create a bloomFilter based on Bit torrent BEP 33.
I have created Bloom Filter but it is not exactly what I am looking for. Here's what I need and I have not completely understood this situation. If someone here can explain ...

```
//fixed parameters

k = 2

m = 256*8

//the filter
byte[m/8] bloom   ## What is this part?

function insertIP(byte[] ip) {

    byte[20] hash = sha1(ip)

    int index1 = hash[0] | hash[1] << 8
    int index2 = hash[2] | hash[3] << 8

    // truncate index to m (11 bits required)
    index1 %= m  ## ?
    index2 %= m  ## ?

    // set bits at index1 and index2
    bloom[index1 / 8] |= 0x01 << index1 % 8   ## ??
    bloom[index2 / 8] |= 0x01 << index2 % 8   ## ??
 }

 // insert IP 192.168.1.1 into the filter:
 insertIP(byte[4] {192,168,1,1})
```

And this is what I have created

```
import hashlib
m = 2048
def hashes(s):
    index = [0, 0]
    #for c in s:
        #o = ord(c)
    index[0] = hashlib.sha224(index[0]).hexdigest ## This needs integer hash
    index[1] = hashlib.sha224(index[1]).hexdigest ## same as above 

    return [x % m for x in index]

class BloomFilter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bitarray = [0] * m

    def add(self, s):
        for x in hashes(s):
            self.bitarray[x] = 1
        #print self.bitarray
    def query(self, s):
        return all(self.bitarray[x] == 1 for x in hashes(s))

shazib=BloomFilter()
shazib.add('192.168.0.1')
print shazib.query('192.168.0.1')
```

Comment: I have written inside the above code. How do I add this filter
byte[m/8] bloom in my code? see comments in the above code the lower code i have created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, an explanation of the code...

```
//fixed parameters

k = 2
```

This is the most baffling line to me; `k` isn't used at all...

```
m = 256*8
```

This is the number of bits in 256 bytes.

```
//the filter
byte[m/8] bloom   ## What is this part?
```

`bloom` is an array of 256 bytes, i.e. 256 * 8 bits, i.e. `m` bits. Each bit in `bloom` will contain information about what values are in the filter.

```
function insertIP(byte[] ip) {

    byte[20] hash = sha1(ip)
```

This creates a 20-byte hash of `ip`.

```
    int index1 = hash[0] | hash[1] << 8
    int index2 = hash[2] | hash[3] << 8
```

These two lines calculate two indices into `bloom` based on the hash. Basically, `index1` is the concatenation of the first two bytes of `hash`, and `index2` is the concatenation of the second two bytes of `hash`.

```
    // truncate index to m (11 bits required)
    index1 %= m  ## ?
    index2 %= m  ## ?
```

These two lines truncate the values so that they don't exceed the range of possible indices into `bloom`. The `%` is the mod operator; it returns the remainder after division. (17 % 4 = 1, 22 % 5 = 2 and so on.) Remember that bloom is 256 * 8 bits long? Eleven bits allows us to encode 2 ** 11 possible indices, i.e. 2048 values, i.e. 256 * 8 values.

```
    // set bits at index1 and index2
    bloom[index1 / 8] |= 0x01 << index1 % 8   ## ??
    bloom[index2 / 8] |= 0x01 << index2 % 8   ## ??
```

We're treating `bloom` as a bit-array, so we have to do some bit-twiddling to access the correct bit. First, divide `indexA` by 8, to get the correct byte, then truncate `indexA` using the `%` operator to get the correct bit within that byte.

```
}

// insert IP 192.168.1.1 into the filter:
insertIP(byte[4] {192,168,1,1})
```

And voila, we have a bloom filter. If you printed it out bitwise, it would look like this:

```
data->    001011000101110011000001001000100...

indices-> 000000000011111111112222222222333...
          012345678901234567890123456789012...
```

And if a particular i.p., when hashed, generates an `index1` of `5` and an `index2` of `9`, then it would be considered "in" the filter, because the bits at indices `5` and `9` are set to `1`. Of course, there can be false positives, because multiple different values could result in the same indices; but there can be no false negatives.

```
import hashlib
m = 2048
def hashes(s):
    index = [0, 0]
    #for c in s:
        #o = ord(c)
    index[0] = hashlib.sha224(index[0]).hexdigest ## This needs integer hash
    index[1] = hashlib.sha224(index[1]).hexdigest ## same as above
```

Here's your first problem. `index[0]` and `index[1]` need to be integers. Also, `hashlib.sha224(index[0]).hexdigest` returns a method. You have to call the method to get anything out of it, like this: `hashlib.sha224(index[0]).hexdigest()`. Also, if you want this to work in a way that's identical to the above code, you could convert the hash to an int (you can use `int(x, 16)` to convert a hexadecimal string into an integer) and then extract the first two bytes using `& 65535`, then shift it by two bytes using `>> 16`, then extract those two bytes using `& 65535` again. Once you've got that correct, the rest works.

```
    return [x % m for x in index]

class BloomFilter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bitarray = [0] * m

    def add(self, s):
        for x in hashes(s):
            self.bitarray[x] = 1
        #print self.bitarray
    def query(self, s):
        return all(self.bitarray[x] == 1 for x in hashes(s))

shazib=BloomFilter()
shazib.add('192.168.0.1')
print shazib.query('192.168.0.1')
```

Comment: Thinking about it more, the below is closer to the original method for extracting the first four bytes. I'm not sure which one is faster. `hbyte = hashlib.sha224('fdsa').digest()` and then `index[0] = ord(hbyte[-1]) | ord(hbyte[-2]) << 8` and `index[1] = ord(hbyte[-3]) | ord(hbyte[-4]) << 8`

Comment: Also, just fyi, the `hashlib` module also has a `sha1` function, and if you want to convert an ip into a sequence of ints, you could do something like this: `[int(x) for x in '192.168.1.1'.split('.')]`